# define class globally in withut require include

Tags: php

I want to define a class globally, so if I create a page this , it works

```
<?php 

$cl = new MyOwnClass();

?>
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You shoulod look into Autoloading Classes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Autoload is probably the feature the OP wants, but he will have to also declare the autoload function is the page, or require/include it. So, he will not have **just** the code that he specifies in the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
class classname
{
    public function publicfuntioname($testvar) { 
        $this->testvar = $testvar; 
    }
}
```

Now include this file any where

```
$obj= new classname();

$obj->publicfuntioname("another value");
```

Comment: He said he doesn't want to have to use include. Autoloading is the answer.